# Modificar o tamanho da imagem de acordo com a URL dela

Tags: javascript, html, css

bom dia! Eu pesquisei (e até achei um js chamado Holder.js que aparentemente faz o que eu quero, mas não consegui entender ele) uma forma de fazer o seguinte:
Url da imagem a 700x700 -> http://www.distribuidoramultmed.com.br/Imagens/BD/bancoDeDados.png

Quero que ela fique 200x200, então passo -> http://www.distribuidoramultmed.com.br/Imagens/BD/bancoDeDados.png/200x200
ou
http://www.distribuidoramultmed.com.br/Imagens/BD/bancoDeDados.png&h=200w200

Resumindo, preciso de uma forma de modificar "dinamicamente" o tamanho da imagem com base na URL.
Eu pesquisei mas não consegui encontrar nada, além do Holder;
Obrigado!

Comment: Talvez sim, talvez não, mas uma busca rápida encontrei [isso aqui](http://www.mobify.com/mobifyjs/v2/docs/image-resizer). Será que não ajuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

essa função é usada pra pegar parâmetros da URL:

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
} ();
```

No seu caso, você vai pegar os dois parâmetros de medida da img:

```
heightImg = QueryString.h
widthImg = QueryString.w
```

Agora que você já tem os parâmentros, basta alterar o tamanho da imagem:

```
$( "#IDimg" ).css( "width": widthImg, "height": heightImg );
```

Apenas uma correção... na hora de passar os parâmentros na URL, tem que ser nesse formato: `URL?w=200&h=200` no seu caso ficaria `http://www.distribuidoramultmed.com.br/Imagens/BD/bancoDeDados.png?h=200w200`

Comment: Negativei a sua resposta por ser incompleta. Ela resolve um dos problemas do OP, mas não responde a pergunta num todo.

Comment: tinha esquecido do resto rs... agora esta completo!

Comment: Agora sim, Thiago! Removi meu -1! Cara, eu só não vou te dar +1 porque essa modificação de largura x altura é totalmente `client-side`. Se ele quiser, por exemplo, colocar a URL da imagem redimensionada em uma tag `<img>`, o efeito desejado não vai funcionar – ele é exclusivo para acesso direto.

Comment: sim mas foi o que ele pediu, alterar a img pela URL (:

Comment: O exemplo da pergunta está errado, tinha que ser **`URL?w=200&h=200`**. Sugiro editar a resposta para deixar a função OK.

Comment: ok valeu, agora esta completo

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas! tirou a minha duvida!

Answer (score 2):

O Holder.js tem como objetivo servir imagens para demonstrações – ele não é um script e/ou plug-in para você cortar as suas imagens baseado em demandas.

Para realizar o seu desejo, cortar uma imagem baseado num parâmetro de URL, você, na verdade, vai usar tecnologia no lado do servidor. Um exemplo é a gem [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) do Rails – ele faz isso para você com muita praticidade.

Se você quiser algo mais específico e detalhado, terá que criar um novo tópico específico para esse assunto, porque no momento você quer saber sobre como realizar essa operação via JavaScript.

Pois bem, com JavaScript o procedimento é um pouco mais... *doloroso*. O [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) é uma plataforma front-end que vai te agilizar o serviço, mas conhecimento sobre JavaScript num todo vai ser super necessário.

**Por que o Backbone.js?**

Ele possui um mecanismo de [rotas](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) que consegue diagnosticar uma solicitação do seu cliente e então fazer algo baseado nisso.

Em palavras simplificadas, o roteamento dele provém a capacidade de observar a URL. Caso ela esteja algo assim: `Imagens/BD/bancoDeDados.png/200x200`, ele consegue determinar o que deve ser feito – isso quando a requisição for assíncrona –, o que, neste caso, é o (re)corte/(re)dimensionamento de uma imagem renderizada baseada em uma URL disponibilizada pelo seu banco de dados – o que ainda vai exigir uma requisição do tipo `GET`, ainda assíncrona, para o servidor.

Para esta outra tarefa – a de recorte –, entretanto, você vai precisar de um [plug-in](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/) ou aprender a fazer um dispositivo do zero.

<sub>***Minha recomendação é você operar isso com uma tecnologia de servidor.***</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!